# upload de imagens + web service php

Tags: php, java, android, upload

Boa pessoal, estou meio atrasado no meu tcc por motivos de não conseguir fazer o upload da imagem. O que tenho hj funcionado e tirar a foto, salvar em no bando sqlite o caminho e latitude e longitude, porem tenho uma tela no meu app que devo enviar uma imagem com um cadastro, o cadastro esta ok somente faltando a imagem. Os dados do cadastro são enviado para um web service em PHP, porem não sei como vou fazer pra enviar a imagem, sendo que tenho que selecionar a imagem da galeria e enviar,retornando o caminho dela e salvar no banco junto com os demais dados do formulario enviado. Se alguem puder me dar um help ai agradeço...

CODIGO DO WEB SERVICE

```
 <?php
 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
require 'connect.php';
inReg();
 }
 function inReg() {

    global $connect;

    $id_usuario = $_POST["id_usuario"];
    $tipo_atividade = $_POST["tipo_atividade"];
    $tipo_local= $_POST["tipo_local"];
    $quantidade = $_POST["quantidade"];


    $query = " Insert into registro_animal(id_usuario, id_tipo_atividade,id_tipo_local,quantidade) values ('$id_usuario','$tipo_atividade','$tipo_local','$quantidade')";
        mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connect));
    mysqli_close($connect);
}

 ?>
```

Comment: Eu sei fazer isso, mas estou no serviço e não posso te ajudar agora! =)

Comment: Sem estresse, a hora que puder me ajudar será ótimo, pois estou atrasado nesta questão. Fico no aguardo!

Comment: Coloquei uma resposta e um link no final que vai te ajudar bastante. Praticamente está pronto para você, só tem que ter as manhas de adaptar ao seu código.

Answer (score 1):

## Recebendo imagem

A princípio é necessário fazer um upload clássico e rápido de apenas um arquivo.  Um dos atributos que não podemos esquecer para fazer `upload`, é o que seta o `enctype` ao nosso formulário. Uma das maneira é usar `method="POST"` e `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

#### Método POST

> Este recurso permite realizar uploads de arquivos de texto e binários.
>   Com as funções de autenticação e manipulação de arquivos do PHP, você
>   tem o controle completo de quem pode fazer o upload e o que deve ser
>   feito com o arquivo após o upload estar completo.

#### PHP

```
if(isset($_FILES['fileUpload'])){
      date_default_timezone_set("Brazil/East"); // definindo timezone padrão

      $ext = strtolower(substr($_FILES['fileUpload']['name'],-4)); //pegando extensão do arquivo
      $new_name = date("Y.m.d-H.i.s") . $ext; //definindo um novo nome para o arquivo
      $dir = 'uploads/'; //diretório de destindo do arquivo

      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'], $dir.$new_name); //Fazer upload do arquivo
   }
```

Como um "boa prática" é definido uma variável com o ano, mês, dia, hora, minuto e segundo, concatenando com a extensão da imagem. Para finalmente fazer o upload do arquivo, é usado a função `move_uploaded_file`, passando dois parâmetros, primeiro o nome temporário da imagem armazenado pelo servidor, e o novo nome do arquivo, já com diretório padrão.

## Enviando imagem

Já no envio por parte do Android, uma das formas é você usar:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Config.FILE_UPLOAD_URL);
```

#### build.gradle

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Para mais detalhes, você pode acessar este artigo [Android Uploading Camera Image, Video to Server with Progress Bar](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/) que te ajudará bastante.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou tentando aqui, qualquer coisa volto a perguntar !